# Google Analytics Data API v1 runReport and only return JSON

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

currently I am trying to get the json data from GA4 using Google Analytics Data API v1. However, the response given back is not a pure json data, instead if I just print it using PHP, it gives me {}. However, using the predefined method, we can get the value. May I know, is there anyway I can get a pure json data?

```
<?php
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=xxx.json');

require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\Connection\Rest;

$property_id = 'xxx'; // GA4 property ID

// Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
// specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
  'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
  'dateRanges' => [
    new DateRange([
      'start_date' => '2022-06-30',
      'end_date' => 'today',
    ]),
  ],
  'dimensions' => [
    new Dimension(
      [
        'name' => 'city',
      ]
    ),
  ],
  'metrics' => [
    new Metric(
      [
        'name' => 'activeUsers',
      ]
    )
  ]
]);

print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

printVisitorsLocationInNumber($response);

function printVisitorsLocationInNumber($resp) {
  foreach ($resp->getRows() as $row) {
    echo
    $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue() . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL . '</br>';;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]  We cant help you determine the issue with your code without seeing your code.  If you are using the client library then it will parse the json into objects for you.

Comment: is there anyway I don't use client library?

Comment: Yes as i stated the api returns Json this is an error in your code.  Please Edit your question and include  Your code -->  [example]  <-- your code.

Comment: Hi I included my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $response->serializeToJsonString(); // Prints JSON string
```

`$response` is an instance of `\Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\RunReportResponse`, which is extended from `\Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message`. Hence, you can use `serializeToJsonString()` method of the same.